# Consumer to enclose try catch logic does not work

Tags: java-8, try-catch, dry

I am refactoring some legacy code and I come across this function:

```
private static void parseOptionalValues(Product product, Input source) {
    try {
        product.setProductType(...some operation with source...);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {}
    try {
        product.setMaterial(...some operation with source...);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {}
    try {
        product.setUnitPricingBaseMeasure(...some operation with source...);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {}
    try {
        product.setUnitPricingMeasure(...some operation with source...);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ignored){}
}
```

My common sense says to me that in order to keep the Don't Repeat Yourself principle I should wrap this try-catch logic so I introduced this change:

```
private static void parseOptionalValues(Product product, Input source) {
    setOptionalParameter(...some operation with source..., product::setProductType);
    setOptionalParameter(...some operation with source..., product::setMaterial);
    setOptionalParameter(...some operation with source..., product::setUnitPricingBaseMeasure);
    setOptionalParameter(...some operation with source..., product::setUnitPricingMeasure);
}

private static <T> void setOptionalParameter(T value, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    try {
        consumer.accept(value);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {}
}
```

I am running some unit tests and debugging but the code doesn't behave as previously as the `IllegalArgumentException` is not catched but raised so the program fails.

Any idea on how to solve this enclosing the try-catch logic in a single place?

Comment: are you sure about the fact that `IllegalArgumentException` is not caught?

Comment: Perhaps, because “some operation with source” throws the exception?

Comment: Exactly, the exceptions are thrown by that part... I realize what you're trying to tell me. In any case, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You can change the caller to, e.g. `setOptionalParameter(product, p -> p.setProductType(...some operation with source...));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be that the exception is thrown by the code that gets the arguments to be passed to the setters. So one possible approach would be to make that part of the code *lazy* by using a `Supplier`, then invoke `.get()` on the `Supplier` inside a the `try/catch` block (as well as invoking the `Consumer`):

```
private static <T> void setOptionalParameter(
        Supplier<? extends T> supplier, 
        Consumer<? super T> consumer) {

    try {
        consumer.accept(supplier.get());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
    }
}
```

You could invoke that method as follows:

```
setOptionalParameter(() -> ...some operation with source..., product::setProductType);
```

Note that I've improved the signature of your method so that it now accepts a wider range of generic subtypes and supertypes for the `Supplier` and `Consumer`, respectively.

---

**EDIT:** As per the comments, the approach above might be not flexible enough, i.e. if the method accepts more than one argument, etc. In this case, it would be better to use a `Runnable` instance:

```
private static void setOptionalParameter(Runnable action) {

    try {
        action.run();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
    }
}
```

And invocation would now become:

```
setOptionalParameter(() -> {
    ProductType productType = ...some operation with source...;
    Material material = ...some operation with source...;

    product.doSomethingWith2Args(productType, material);
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys. With the runnable works like a charm. Also you help me understanding what was happening